# How to block certain contents and files from downloading on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, home-networking, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

I want to to block some video files from downloading when I browse PSN webpage due the network bandwidth shortage in my area, the url is something like this: `https://apollo*.dl.playstation.net/*.mp4`

Ad blocks do not work because it is downloaded via js script. And my router cannot block https urls nor the ability to translate wildcard urls.

Any tool or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Load chrome://settings/content in the browser's address bar.

Locate the plugins section on the page that opens.

Switch the setting to let me choose when to run plugin content.